# Linux $PATH variable autoupdates

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I have a problem on my Ubuntu 18.04 , I set PATH variable , and it works fine but after some time it reverts my changes. I do something like:
`export $PATH=$PATH:/my/dir/bin` .

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add it to your `.bashrc`, and make it permanent. 
Using any text editor, edit `~/.bashrc`, and add the line you need.
Then source it, `source ~/.bashrc`.

Answer (score 0):

With the export command the new PATH variable will be only available at the current terminal session. To make it permanent over the different sessions you will need to add it to the ~/.bashrc file.

Answer (score 0):

That call will only work for your terminal session, you need to edit your ~/.profile or ~/.bashrc file, and put the path in there then start a new terminal session